# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que un programa recoja los valores deseados y los muestre en pantalla?

Tags: c#

```
namespace condicionalIF
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Solo aquellas personas que tienen un sueldo menor de 20$ al mes podran optar por las ayudas del Estado");

            Console.WriteLine("Entregame el listado de aquellos que van a recibir las ayudas:");

            Console.WriteLine("¿Cual es el sueldo de Pedro?");
            int sueldoPedro = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (sueldoPedro <= 20) Console.WriteLine("Pedro");
            else { Console.WriteLine("No puede recibir ayudas"); }

            Console.WriteLine("¿Cual es el sueldo de Maria?");
            int sueldoMaria = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (sueldoMaria <= 20) Console.WriteLine("Maria");
            else { Console.WriteLine("No puede recibir ayudas"); }

            Console.WriteLine("¿Cual es el sueldo de Antonio?");
            int sueldoAntonio = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (sueldoAntonio <= 20) Console.WriteLine("Antonio");
            else { Console.WriteLine("No puede recibir ayudas"); }

            Console.WriteLine("¿Cual es el sueldo de Sandra?");
            int sueldoSandra = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (sueldoSandra <= 20) Console.WriteLine("Sandra");
            else { Console.WriteLine("No puede recibir ayudas"); }

           

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

A ver si me explico bien, como pueden ver estoy haciendo un programa que determine el tipo de personas que pueden recibir una ayuda del gobierno.

Ahora bien, yo quiero hacer que al final del programa la aplicación pueda "recoger" aquellas personas que cumplan con las condiciones previamente establecidas, entiéndase, quiero que al final el programa me muestre algo así como:

"solo Pedro y Maria cumplen las condiciones"

Para ser más claro, no es que yo lo voy a configurar de esa forma, sino que luego de que el usurio haya ingresado el sueldo de cada persona, el mismo programa pueda identificar aquellos que cumplan con las condiciones y muestre quienes son los que pueden recibir la ayuda...

Me disculpan si no me di a entender del todo, soy nuevo en esto de la programación y todavía me falta mucho por aprender, gracias de antemano.

Comment: pero lo esta haciendo el programa. Cual es la duda que tenes en particular?

Comment: O sea, quiero que el programa al final me muestre en una especie de lista de quienes son los que pueden recibir las ayudas, algo así como:                               "Solo tal o cual persona puede recibir ayudas"

Comment: ok.. sabes como construir un string? si no, averigua como construir un string (como concatenar pedazos para ir escribiendo lo que queres) y sigamos por ahi

Comment: Esta bien,  ahora mismo lo hago y luego te digo que tal, gracias.

Comment: @RicardoDeLaCruz, ¿cómo vas con la recomendación de gbianchi? Si encontraste la solución considera publicar tu propia respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Viendo el nombre del namespace, veo que estas revisando el condicional, por lo que te dejo un código parecido al tuyo y sencillo. Este ejercicio es mejor hacerlo con ciclos, programación orientada a objetos, etc. Pero te dejo un código sencillo, va dentro del main:

```
string personas = "Las personas que cumplen las condiciones son: ";//esta variable es para concatenar los nombres

            int sueldo = 0;//variable para guardar los sueldos

            Console.WriteLine("Solo aquellas personas que tienen un sueldo menor de 20$ al mes podran optar por las ayudas del Estado");

            Console.WriteLine("Entregame el listado de aquellos que van a recibir las ayudas:");

            Console.WriteLine("¿Cual es el sueldo de Pedro?");
            sueldo = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());// solo puede recibir números, si ingresas una letra te va a arrojar una excepción de formato, ya que no puede convertir una letra a numero.
            if (sueldo <= 20)
            {
                personas += "Pedro, ";//pongo += para concatenar lo que tenia antes
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Pedro no puede recibir ayudas");
            }
            sueldo = 0; //luego de leer, vuelvo a poner en 0 la variable por las dudas

            Console.WriteLine("¿Cual es el sueldo de Maria?");
            sueldo = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (sueldo <= 20)
            {
                personas += "Maria, ";
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Maria no puede recibir ayudas");
            }
            sueldo = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("¿Cual es el sueldo de Antonio?");
            sueldo = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (sueldo <= 20)
            {
                personas += "Antonio, ";
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Antonio no puede recibir ayudas");
            }
            sueldo = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("¿Cual es el sueldo de Sandra?");
            sueldo = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (sueldo <= 20)
            {
                personas += "Sandra. ";
            }
            else
            {
                personas +=".";  
                Console.WriteLine("Sandra no puede recibir ayudas");
            }
            sueldo = 0;

            Console.WriteLine(personas); //muestro el resultado final
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

lo probé y se ve así, espero que sea lo que buscas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -1):

@RicardoDeLaCruz , si todavía sigues en busca de una solución prueba a concatenar el string que deseas con [StringBuilder](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/base-types/stringbuilder), aquí te dejo también otro link donde te muestra como utilizarlo de diversas [formas / ejemplos](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-stringbuilder).

Un ejemplo sencillo para tu caso sería algo como:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); //Inicializacion de StringBuilder
sb.Append("Las personas que cumplen las condiciones son: ");

Console.WriteLine("¿Cual es el sueldo de Pedro?");
sueldo = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
if (sueldo <= 20)
{
   sb.AppendLine("Pedro");
}
else
{
   Console.WriteLine("Pedro no puede recibir ayudas");
}
sueldo = 0; 
Console.WriteLine(sb);
```

También te recomiendo que si se trabajase sobre una `List<Personas>` te sería mas fácil y te quedaría mas limpio.
Ejemplo:

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("Las personas que cumplen las condiciones son: ");
    
    List<string> PersonasList = new List<string>();
    int sueldo = 0;
    
    Console.WriteLine("Solo aquellas personas que tienen un sueldo menor de 20$ al mes podran optar por las ayudas del Estado");
    
    Console.WriteLine("Entregame el listado de aquellos que van a recibir las ayudas:");
    
    PersonasList.Add("Pedro"); PersonasList.Add("Maria"); PersonasList.Add("Antonio"); PersonasList.Add("Sandra");
    
    foreach (string Persona in PersonasList)
    {
    Console.WriteLine($"¿Cual es el sueldo de {Persona}?");
    sueldo = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    if (sueldo <= 20)
    {
    sb.AppendLine(Persona);
    }
    else
    {
    Console.WriteLine($"{Persona} no puede recibir ayudas");
    }
    sueldo = 0;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(sb);
```

Si quisieras que los nombre te saliesen seguidos horizontalmente, deberias cambiar el `sb.AppendLine(Persona);` por `sb.Append($"{Persona}, ");`

Un saludo

Comment: Procura que cualquier respuesta no sea sólo un enlace a otra parte. Cuando ese enlace se rompa, la respuesta se hace inservible para cualquiera que venga a revisarla / usarla. Una breve reseña de qué código usar, un ejemplo básico, una serie de pasos... algo así.

Comment: pues mira que no puedo porque no la he votado :)  Lo que sí debo decir es que agradezco el que te hayas tomado el tiempo de recibir la sugerencia y tu respuesta es mucho más clara ahora!